# How can I get a list of all users in groups linked to the admin?

Tags: c#, linq

---

For example, I have 3 groups with following ids: `1`, `2`, `3`;

```
 id | name     |
 ---------------
  1  |  group1 | 
  2  |  group2 | 
  3  |  group3 |
```

Also, I have users in those groups: 2 in group `1`, 3 in group `2` and 1 in group `3`;

```
 id | user | groupid |
 ---------------------
  1  |  user1 | 1
  2  |  user2 | 1
  3  |  user3 | 2
  4  |  user4 | 2
  5  |  user5 | 2
  6  |  user6 | 3
```

And of course I have the table admgroups

```
id | groupid | admid |
----------------------
1  |  1      | 3     |
2  |  2      | 4     |
3  |  3      | 3     |
4  |  2      | 5     |
```

All I want to get - a list which should include all users from groups, that are linked to admin, for example, with id = 3. So the result should be like:
`var list = {"user1", "user2", "user6"}`

Comment: May the group have more than one admin?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `select` likes the following. First, find the `groupid`s related to the specified admin. Then, select users which have the selected `groupid`:

```
var admin_id = 3;
var admin_groups = admgroups.Where(x=> x.admid == admin_id).Select(x=> x.groupid).ToList();
var result = users.Select(x=> admin_groups.Contains(x.groupid)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put those lines in your code:

```
var list = (from cl in (from adm in admgroups
                join gr in groups
                    on adm.groupid equals gr.Id
                where adm.admid==3
                select new {gr.Id})
                join client in users
                on cl.Id equals client.groupid
                        select new {client.user}).ToList();
```